# Javascript Exporting Table data to csv without html tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to export some data from a table into a csv file without having to use plugins so I found this code:

```
jQuery("#exportButton").click(function (e) {
     window.open('data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + jQuery('#myTable').html());
            e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code works but it's saving the html tags too. 
So how can I export data from the table in a similar way without having the html tags in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question interested me. So i try and it's possible : 
https://jsfiddle.net/ouvaztan/

HTML :

```
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

JS :

```
$(function() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var data = ($("#customers").text().trim().replace(/[\n]+/g, ";").replace(/  /g, "").replace(/;;;/g, ";\n") + ";").replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
    link.download = "test.csv";
    link.href = 'data:application/csv;base64,' + btoa(data);
    link.click();
});
```

There is a limitation : 
all lines and columns have to contain text and colspan/rowspan is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Just for the matter of extracting text you can use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

But it will be a bit trickier to extract text in a particular format.